# Centering & filling this element

Tags: html, css, css-position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Animated Bars</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: black; /* Sets the background color of the entire page to black. */
        }

        #bars {
            position: absolute; /* Positions the element absolutely within its containing element. */
            top: 0; /* Positions the element vertically at the center of its parent. */    
            bottom: 10;
            height: 14px; /* Sets the height of the element to 14 pixels. */
            transform: scale(2) translateX(-5%) translateY(0%); /* Applies a scaling and translation transform to the element. */
        }

        .bar {
            position: absolute; /* Positions the element absolutely within its containing element. */
            bottom: 0px; /* Positions the element at the bottom of its parent. */
            height: 3px; /* Sets the height of the element to 3 pixels. */
            width: 1px; /* Sets the width of the element to 1 pixel. */
            background: white; /* Sets the background color of the element to white. */
            animation: sound 0ms -1000ms linear infinite alternate; /* Defines the animation for the element. */
            transform: translateY(50%) TranslateX(50%); /* Applies a translation transform to the element. */
        }

        @keyframes sound {
            0% {
                opacity: .80; /* Sets the opacity of the element at the start of the animation. */
                height: 20px; /* Sets the height of the element at the start of the animation. */
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1; /* Sets the opacity of the element at the end of the animation. */
                height: 75px; /* Sets the height of the element at the end of the animation. */
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bars"></div> /* Creates a container with the id "bars" to hold the animated bars. */

    <script>
        
        function randomColor() {
            const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'; /* Defines a set of characters for creating random colors. */
            let color = '#'; /* Initializes a color with a hash symbol. */
            for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]; /* Generates a random color. */
            }
            return color; /* Returns the generated color. */
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
            const left = (i * 2) + 1; /* Calculates the left position of each bar. */
            const anim = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75 + 400); /* Generates a random animation duration. */
            const height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 + 3); /* Generates a random bar height. */

            // Calculate a gradient color based on the position of the bar
            const color = `hsl(${(i / 90) * 360}, 100%, 50%)`; /* Calculates a gradient color. */

            const bar = document.createElement('div'); /* Creates a new div element for a bar. */
            bar.className = 'bar'; /* Assigns the "bar" class to the div element. */
            bar.style.left = left + 'px'; /* Sets the left position of the bar. */
            bar.style.animationDuration = anim + 'ms'; /* Sets the animation duration for the bar. */
            bar.style.height = height + 'px'; /* Sets the height of the bar. */
            bar.style.background = color; /* Sets the background color of the bar. */
            document.querySelector('#bars').appendChild(bar); /* Appends the bar to the "bars" container. */
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am fairly new to html, css and js. I am making a website and I want this soundwave to appear. I've found a soundwave, and changed it a bit to my preferences but I can't get it to fit the screen. The only way i've found is by setting the #bars positioning to fixed, but then obviously it stays when I scroll. I have tried changing everything, centering everything, using vh and vw but nothing seems to work. With some help of ChatGPT and blackbox, I now understand the code but still can't make it fit. Can someone help me make this fit every screensize and explain me what I missed?.

I want it to fit every screensize without expanding to the left and making the window larger than the screen.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Animated Bars</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            /* Clear the default margin and padding */
            width: 100%;
            /* Set the width of body to full viewport */
            background-color: #181A1D;
            /* Sets the background color of the entire page to black. */
        }

        #bars {
            outline: 2px solid #EFF8;
            /* Gives an outline to the element */
            outline-offset: -3px;
            /* Offset from the original position of outline */
            height: 90px;
            /* Height of the container */
            width: 100%;
            /* Width full to viewport */
            display: flex;
            /* Makes the container a flexbox */
            flex-direction: row;
            /* Sets the direction of items in the flexbox */
            align-items: center;
            /* Align the items in center on vertical axis of container (flexbox) */
            justify-content: center;
            /* Align the items in center horizontal axis of container (flexbox) */
            overflow: hidden;
            /* Hides any element inside it which does not fit inside it */
            padding: 22px 0;
            /* Gives padding in the x axis. this is to make sure that bars that scale up more than the height of the parent do not get hidden */
        }

        .bar {
            width: 2px;
            margin: 0 0.5px;
            /* vertical and horizontal axis margin from other elements */
            height: 50%;
            /* Height (% means relative to its parent height) */
            background-color: #FFF;
            border-radius: 5px;
            /* Makes the corners of the element round (takes the radius of the roundness) */
            animation: sound 0ms -1000ms linear infinite alternate;
        }

        @keyframes sound {
            0% {
                opacity: .75;
                /* Sets the opacity of the element at the start of the animation. */
                scale: 1 0.5;
                /* Scales the element from its original size (in this condition height) to specified value (1 means 100% and 0 means 0%) */
                /* first value determines scaling in X or horizontal axis and second one in Y axis */
            }

            100% {
                opacity: 1;
                /* Sets the opacity of the element at the end of the animation. */
                scale: 1.2 2;
                /* scaling width to 1.2 times and height to 2 times */
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bars"></div> /* Creates a container with the id "bars" to hold the animated bars. */

    <script>

        function randomColor() {
            const letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'; /* Defines a set of characters for creating random colors. */
            let color = '#'; /* Initializes a color with a hash symbol. */
            for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]; /* Generates a random color. */
            }
            return color; /* Returns the generated color. */
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            const anim = Math.floor(Math.random() * 75 + 400); /* Generates a random animation duration. */
            const height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50); /* Generates a random bar height. */

            // Calculate a gradient color based on the position of the bar
            const color = `hsl(${(i / 90) * 360}, 100%, 50%)`; /* Calculates a gradient color. */

            const bar = document.createElement('div'); /* Creates a new div element for a bar. */
            bar.className = 'bar'; /* Assigns the "bar" class to the div element. */
            bar.style.animationDuration = anim + 'ms'; /* Sets the animation duration for the bar. */
            bar.style.animationDelay = (Math.random() * anim) + 'ms'; /* Sets the animation delay for the bar. */
            bar.style.height = height + '%'; /* Sets the height of the bar. */
            bar.style.background = color; /* Sets the background color of the bar. */
            document.querySelector('#bars').appendChild(bar); /* Appends the bar to the "bars" container. */
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Made some changes in the styling
I have added appropriate comments to clear things up

Instead of positioning all the bars absolute it is better to put them in a flexbox and align them all in a row.
And instead of animating height, it is better to change the scale of the bars.
Scaling is better for performance than changing height.

// hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! I only have one question left. When I display it on a phone screen, it doesn't appear. I think the screen is too small to show this. Can I resolve this (easily)?

Comment: That is not visible on mobile devices becaue the container is getting so squeezed that the individual bar is getting invisible.

SOLUTION:- give a min-width to #bars for example 900px so that it does not get squeezed and also set min-width to .bar and try to keep the min-width value same as width which is here 2px